# LeetCode 380: Insert Delete GetRandom O(1)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, testcase

I came across this leetcode problem [Insert Delete GetRandom](https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1/) where it is asked to implement a Data Structure to support Insert, Delete and getRandom in average O(1) time, and solved it as using map and a vector.
My solution passes all the test cases except for the last one and I'm not able to figure out why? The last test case is really very large to debug.

I changed my code a little bit and then it passes but still didn't got why the previous one didn't pass.

**Non-Accepted Solution**:

```
class RandomizedSet {
map<int, int> mp;
vector<int> v;

public:
/** Initialize your data structure here. */
RandomizedSet() {

}

/** Inserts a value to the set. Returns true if the set did not already contain the specified element. */
bool insert(int val) {
    if(mp.find(val) == mp.end()){

            v.push_back(val);
            mp[val] = v.size()-1;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

/** Removes a value from the set. Returns true if the set contained the specified element. */
bool remove(int val) {
    if(mp.find(val) == mp.end()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
         int idx = mp[val];
         mp.erase(val);
         swap(v[idx], v[v.size()-1]);
         v.pop_back();
        if(mp.size()!=0) mp[v[idx]] = idx;

         return true;
    }
}

/** Get a random element from the set. */
int getRandom() {
    if(v.size() == 0) return 0;
    int rndm = rand()%v.size();
    return v[rndm];
}
};

/**
 * Your RandomizedSet object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * RandomizedSet* obj = new RandomizedSet();
 * bool param_1 = obj->insert(val);
 * bool param_2 = obj->remove(val);
 * int param_3 = obj->getRandom();
 */
```

**Accpeted Solution:**
The problem is in remove function, when i change the remove function by below code, it passes.

```
    if(mp.find(val) == mp.end()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
         int idx = mp[val];

         swap(v[idx], v[v.size()-1]);
         v.pop_back();
         mp[v[idx]] = idx;
         mp.erase(val);
         return true;
    }
```

I don't understand why is this happening. I placed the `mp.erase(val)` in the last and replaced the `if(mp.size()!=0) mp[v[idx]] = idx` to `mp[v[idx]] = idx` only.

Both versions of remove function are able to handle corner case - when there is only single element left in the map and we want to remove it.

[LeetCode 380](https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1/)

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work. Does it only work for logged in users?

Comment: @HariMenon check now pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of undefined behavior when the element removed is the last element.

e.g, say the operations are

```
insert(1) // v = [1], mp = [1->0]
insert(2) // v = [1,2], mp = [1->0, 2->1]
remove(2):

int idx = mp[val]; // val = 2, idx = 1
mp.erase(val); // mp = [1->0]
swap(v[idx], v[v.size()-1]); // idx = v.size()-1 = 1, so this does nothing.
v.pop_back(); // v = [1]
if(mp.size()!=0) mp[v[idx]] = idx; // mp[v[1]] = 1. 
// But v[1] is undefined after pop_back(), since v's size is 1 at this point.
```

I am guessing that it doesn't clear the memory location accessed by v[1], so v[1] still points to 2, and it ends up putting 2 back into mp.

Comment: No, pls look again, i'm already erasing the value from map. so when i will do remove(2), first it will get erased from the map and then i'm checking if(mp.size()!=0) mp[v[idx]] = idx, it will prevent form the case when i'm only having a single element in the container and it is asked to remove.

Comment: Ah, I had misread it. Updated my answer. This should be it.